# DNS Lookups for local MAMP web server URL taking 5+ seconds

Tags: domain-name-system, localhost, mamp

I'm running MAMP on OS X 10.7. I've set up a virtual host in Apache, like so:

```
<Directory "/sites/example.com/">
Allow From All
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName "example.local"
    ServerAlias "www.example.local"
    DocumentRoot "/sites/example.com"
</VirtualHost>
```

In /etc/hosts I've added this:

```
127.0.0.1 example.local
```

Everything works fine, and up to maybe a week or two ago was very fast. I'm not sure what changed, but now the DNS Lookup portion of the request takes upwards of 5 seconds nearly every time the page is loaded, as reported by both Firebug and Chrome.

Pinging the local address looks good:

```
->ping example.local
PING example.local (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.073 ms
```

Here's what Chrome shows:

[image: Chrome Network Panel Output]

If I refresh immediately after the first connection, the DNS lookup appears to be cached. But refreshing again a short time later causes the slow lookup again.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `example.local` is typically an mDNS (Zeroconf) address, so there's every possibility that your mDNS config has broken in some way, and it's taking a few seconds for that to timeout before it falls back to `/etc/hosts`.

Why not just add `localhost` as a `ServerAlias` and just access it via that name?  Otherwise, at least use a domain that doesn't have a top-level domain that has a different meaning to your system.

Comment: Thanks, changing to example.dev seems to have solved this issue. Any hints on how I can see where mDNS may be having an issue? As I said, this worked fine for a long while and only recently started acting up.

Comment: @Ian and rest of world: I am facing the same problem. any hints on solving it and still using anything.local as an domain?

Comment: @scube: You've got two choices: tell your system not to interpret `.local` as being an mDNS domain, or use something that your system doesn't interpret as an mDNS domain.

Answer (score 2):

Yuo can also use domains which don't have .something, so just `example` without the `.local`. As mentioned here http://www.justincarmony.com/blog/2011/07/27/mac-os-x-lion-etc-hosts-bugs-and-dns-resolution/ it appears OSX uses the .local for Bonjour.

I tested using just example without the .local and it appears to be solving this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this issue with non .local sites when using AJAX- I managed to fix it by adding the following lines to /etc/hosts

```
::1 slow-site.url      
fe80::1%lo0 slow-site.url
```

above the main block of sites for each offending site where 'slow-site.url' is 'example.local' or whatever.

it's a IPv6 address - more details here:

https://superuser.com/questions/241642/what-is-the-relevance-of-fe801lo0-localhost-in-etc-hosts